# I can't update Eclipse 3.5 up to 3.6. If I install 3.6 over it, will I retain my plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclim

When I go to Help->Check for Updates in Eclipse, it checks all the repositories and says "Nothing to update", but my Eclipse version is 3.5.2.R35... I am trying to install the eclim plugin and that requires Eclipse 3.6.x.

If I install Eclipse 3.6 from the eclipse.org website, would that preserve the plugins and configuration I currently have installed?

Thanks!
-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually changes between minor versions (3.x) are big enough to break any plugin functionality. You should find out whether specific plugins you're using support newer version of Eclipse.
You can always download a newer version of Eclipse and install it to different directory and run it from there to test your plugins (which you'll have to install once again to a newer platform). You'll always be able to go back to the older version.